# Is $\{(1,0),(0,0)\}\cup\bigcup_{n\neq1}\{(x,\frac{1}{n}):x\in\Bbb{R}\}$ locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let
>   $X=\{(1,0),(0,0)\}\cup\bigcup_{n\neq1}\{(x,\frac{1}{n}):x\in\Bbb{R}\}$.
>   Determine whether or not $X$ is locally connected and find its
>   components.

Well, I know that a space $X$ is said to be **locally connected at x** if for every neighborhood $U\subset X$ of $x$, there is a connected neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V\subset U$. And the **components**  of $X$ are the equivalence classes of the relation $x\sim y$ if and only if there is a connected subspace of $X$ containing both $x$ and $y$.

Though the definitions of local connectness and components seem clear, this would be the first time I need to deal with a problem like this one, and I'm more interesting to know if there's a strategy to follow in this kind of problems. So where should I look in the first place to prove or disprove the local connectednes of this space? Any hint that can point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The strategy is to look at the members of a neighborhood base of a point and see which ,if any, are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, around $(0, 0)$ there does not exist a connected neighbourhood. This is because if $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, then $(X \setminus \{(0,0)\}) \cap B_\epsilon((0,0)) \neq \emptyset$, and because the connected components are given by

$$
\{(x, 1/n)|x \in \mathbb R\}, n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\} \text{ and } \{(1, 0)\} \text{ and } \{(0, 0)\};
$$

for, each is path-connected and if one contains a point of the other, we already have a partition into two disjoint open subsets.

The space looks roughly like this:

---

---

---

.                   .

The lines are supposed to be closer together the lower they are, but I can't type that, and I also can't type infinitely many lines.

Comment: Okay, I'm beggining to understand it, though it's still difficult to picture the whole space $X$. If instead of taking an ball around $(0,0)$ we take a ball around $(1,0)$, would it also prove that $X$ is not locally connected?

Comment: Yes, indeed, with the very same argument @A.Jiménez